# Dell XPS 13 touchscreen not working, sound not working

Tags: sound, 14.04, dell, touchscreen, xps

All of a sudden the touchscreen on my laptop stopped working, and the sound does not recognise my headphones. I have not installed anything recently, just the usual, minor LTS updates.

The touchscreen is apparently not  recognised:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

And my sound often freezes up now, it doesn't recognize my headphones when I plug them in and when using a bluetooth headset, the output is very noisy and muffled.

I would prefer not to do a re-install because my laptop (Dell XPS 13) took me almost a week to get working due to drivers not working, and with exams coming up I don't have time/patience to redo everything :/

Thanks,

Max

Comment: Is listed with `libinput-list-devices`? Respond to events after running `libinput-debug-events`? And with `evtest`? All this after temporary removing kernel module with `sudo modprobe -r usbtouchscreen`?